# Printing in a loop

Tags: python, printing, for-loop

I have the following file I'm trying to manipulate.

```
 1  2 -3 5  10  8.2
 5  8  5 4  0   6
 4  3  2 3 -2   15
 -3 4  0 2  4   2.33
 2  1  1 1  2.5 0
 0  2  6 0  8   5
```

The file just contains numbers.

I'm trying to write a program to subtract the rows from each other and print the results to a file. My program is below and, `dtest.txt` is the name of the input file. The name of the program is `make_distance.py`.

```
from math import *

posnfile = open("dtest.txt","r")
posn = posnfile.readlines()
posnfile.close()

for i in range (len(posn)-1):
    for j in range (0,1):
        if (j == 0):
            Xp = float(posn[i].split()[0])
            Yp = float(posn[i].split()[1])
            Zp = float(posn[i].split()[2])

            Xc = float(posn[i+1].split()[0])
            Yc = float(posn[i+1].split()[1])
            Zc = float(posn[i+1].split()[2])
        else:
            Xp = float(posn[i].split()[3*j+1])
            Yp = float(posn[i].split()[3*j+2])
            Zp = float(posn[i].split()[3*j+3])

            Xc = float(posn[i+1].split()[3*j+1])
            Yc = float(posn[i+1].split()[3*j+2])
            Zc = float(posn[i+1].split()[3*j+3])

        Px = fabs(Xc-Xp)
        Py = fabs(Yc-Yp)
        Pz = fabs(Zc-Zp)
        print Px,Py,Pz
```

The program is calculating the values correctly but, when I try to call the program to write the output file,

```
mpipython make_distance.py > distance.dat
```

The output file (`distance.dat`) only contains 3 columns when it should contain 6. How do I tell the program to shift what columns to print to for each step j=0,1,....

For j = 0, the program should output to the first 3 columns, for j = 1 the program should output to the second 3 columns (3,4,5) and so on and so forth.

Finally the `len` function gives the number of rows in the input file but, what function gives the number of columns in the file?

Thanks.

Comment: `print 1, 2, 3` and then again `print 1, 2, 3` prints in two lines...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to:

- use numpy
- read the whole file in at once
- know how many columns
- use awkward comma at end of print statement
- use list subscripting
- use math.fabs()
- explicitly close your file

Try this (untested):

```
with open("dtest.txt", "r") as posnfile:
    previous = None
    for line in posnfile:
        current = [float(x) for x in line.split()]
        if previous:
            delta = [abs(c - p) for c, p in zip(current, previous)]
            print ' '.join(str(d) for d in delta)
        previous = current
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with this code. This gives me the exact output I'm looking for. I'm a PhD student in Structural Engineering but, a programmer I'm not.

Comment: @Cloud Strife: Thank you for the kind words. Please consider accepting the answer -- click on the big "tick" at the left.

Answer (score 5):

Append a `,` to the end of your `print` statement and it will not print a newline, and then when you exit the for loop add an additional `print` to move to the next row:

```
for j in range (0,1):
    ...

    print Px,Py,Pz,
print
```

Assuming all rows have the same number of columns, you can get the number of columns by using `len(row.split())`.

Also, you can definitely shorten your code quite a bit, I'm not sure what the purpose of `j` is, but the following should be equivalent to what you're doing now:

```
    for j in range (0,1):
        Xp, Yp, Zp = map(float, posn[i].split()[3*j:3*j+3])
        Xc, Yc, Zc = map(float, posn[i+1].split()[3*j:3*j+3])
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

just in case your `dtest.txt` grows larger and you don't want to redirect your output but rather write to `distance.dat`, especially, if you want to use `numpy`. Thank @John for pointing out my mistake in the old code ;-)

```
import numpy as np
pos = np.genfromtxt("dtest.txt")
dis = np.array([np.abs(pos[j+1] - pos[j]) for j in xrange(len(pos)-1)])
np.savetxt("distance.dat",dis)
```

Comment: Are you sure that this does what the OP wanted? Your code appears to print delta between 2 points in the same line. His code prints deltas between points in adjacent lines.

Comment: @JohnMachin Ooops, my bad! just fixed it.

Comment: `xrange(len(the_whole_file))` ... just in case his file grows larger?

Comment: Good catch...is `pos.shape(0)` good enough? or simply stop reading the whole file but just stream through it? I guess I'm just too numpy-biased ;-)

Comment: Don't be a numpy :-) Read my answer.